# Error occured in eclipse logcat while connecting Android with MySQL database using php 1

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
I am using the code I found in the following tutorial to connect an Android application with a MySQL database with the help of a php script I found here
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
    I downloaded the code and tried executing the project in the emulator.My application is created in emulator and I am able to do `mainscreenactivity` but not able to move to next activity to do `CRUD` operation.In the emulator, after loading it says, unfortunately, 
`MainScreen has stopped` as a popup message. My application name is `MainScreen`. I checked my Eclipse LogCat and it shows following errors. I'd be grateful if someone could help me fix this.

**Logcat:**

```
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5daa8 that was originally bound here
```

12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5daa8 that was originally bound here
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-12 07:41:01.496: E/ActivityThread(685):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685): null
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5daa8 that was originally bound here
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-12 07:41:01.526: E/StrictMode(685):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

**Mysql Database:**

```
CREATE DATABASE androidhive;

CREATE TABLE products(
pid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(100) not null,
price decimal(10,2) not null,
description text,
created_at timestamp default now(),
updated_at timestamp
);

**php script:**

**db_config.php**

db_config.php
<?php

/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "androidhive"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
?>

**db_connect.php**

db_connect.php
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>

**Mysql CRUD operation:**

**Creating a row:**

**create_product.php**

<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>

**Reading a row:**

**get_product_details.php**

<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
            $product["name"] = $result["name"];
            $product["price"] = $result["price"];
            $product["description"] = $result["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>

**Reading all rows:**

**get_all_products.php**

<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>

**Updating a row:**

**update_product.php**

<?php

/*
 * Following code will update a product information
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name = '$name', price = '$price', description = '$description' WHERE pid = $pid");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully updated.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>

**Deleting a row:**

**delete_product.php**

<?php

/*
 * Following code will delete a product from table
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");

    // check if row deleted or not
    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully deleted";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

My android code is in my second post.Please check the code and suggest me something to fix the errors.

Comment: Please post your question with code as clear as possible. Try to debug your code, so that you would get to know at which part you are going wrong. It's a better practice if you paste that snippet.

Comment: What is that above URL? You want others to follow that tutorial and then they could answer?

Comment: I am a beginner to android development.I already told that I downloaded the entire code and did as per suggestions given there.Moreover I used WAMP server to create MySQL database and for php script.I am hosting it locally using  localhost.As Appu asks about the code right, the entire code is in that link.Thats why I suggest that URL otherwise I won't.Don't mistake me Kanth

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below two lines of code in your oncreate() method.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

BTW, you might have other reasons too for not getting the output besides this. But I am not able to answer as you didn't provide your code. If you edit your question with more details, I may be answering those if I could.

Comment: Check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ You can find entire project with video tutorial.Please give me some other suggestions>Above one is not working.